# Strange generic error with AWS Cognito javascript- response encrypted?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, encryption

I am trying to implement Cognito via javascript into my web application. I intend to allow login via facebook and google, but for now I'm just trying to set up user registration and login via cognito. I followed the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-user

This is what my signup code looks like:

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1'; // Region
AWSCognito.config.region = 'us-east-1';
AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-xxx' // your identity pool id here
});

var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: 'us-east-xxx',
    ClientId: 'xxx',
    Paranoia: 7
});
console.log(userPool, 'userPool')

var attributeList = [
    new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute({
        Name: 'email',
        Value: email
    }),
    new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute({
        Name: 'preferred_username',
        Value: username
    }),
    new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute({
        Name: 'phone_number',
        Value: phone
    }),
    new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute({
        Name: 'given_name',
        Value: firstname
    }),
    new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserAttribute({
        Name: 'family_name',
        Value: lastname
    })
];

    userPool.signUp(this.state.signup.username, this.state.signup.password, attributeList, null, function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        cognitoUser = result.user;
        console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
    });
```

The code actually works fine. The user gets created in my user pool (I can see the user in my Cognito admin console. But when I submit the form that runs this code, I get an error in my javascript console that just says "Error". When I inspect the API response it says "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". Then I inspect the raw response and it's just a long sequence of seemingly random characters. I can't figure out if the response is encrypted or base64 encoded or what... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not try decoding it if you think it might be base64?

Comment: *taps his nose twice*... thanks

Comment: Hehe, no problem. Hope that solved it :)

Comment: Well, yes and no. It was definitely base64 encoded, but I can't figure out why. And I can't find anywhere in the docs that say anything whatsoever about base64 encoding the response. I have no way to hook into it and decode it. It's quite frustrating. Like, for instance in that signup method... the callback function never gets called because it chokes on the base64 encoded response